# Kindle: available languages and tools

Tags: kindle

I want to develop my own Kindle app. After some googling I'm pretty confused. What I'm trying to find out is basically:

1. What programming languages are available? Are some of them more popular than others (and why)?
2. What tools do I minimally need? (Simulator, emulator, Kindle device, specialized IDE)
3. Do I need some SDK or similar (on few places Amazon Mobile SDK is mentioned, so it sounds like a good suspect)?
4. Are only Kindle fire and newer devices programmable?

Are there any good links / tutorials you can recommend? Or at least how do I go about finding the answers?

Comment: There is a big different between a regular Kindle and a Kindle Fire the Kindle fire is a Android tablet the regular kindle is an eBook reader...